# Regex: How to parsing problem ID and time stamp event string

Tags: regex

I have the below string that I receive from dynatrace and I need to parse out the Contact POC, the summary which is after the -, the Problem ID which begins with and includes the P-, and the date and time.

Examples:
Contact POC = testuser@abc.com
Summary = Failure rate increase
Problem ID = P-21077840
Date/Time = 13:13 (EDT) 29.07.2021

```
Contact POC: testuser@abc.com - Failure rate increase Impact: OPEN Problem P-21077840 in environment dynatrace_prod Problem detected at: 13:13 (EDT) 29.07.2021 1 impacted service Database service oracle-db-cert Failure rate increase 11.6 requests/min impacted by a failure rate increase to 32 % Service method: Insert into mm_id_map https://testing.abc.com/e/223cc1d7-7ac5-407e-aee0-f60bf83ff6ec/#problems/problemdetails;pid=8355272792722950669_1627578780000V2
```

I have made some progress but got lost with parsing the ID and date/time.

https://regex101.com/r/nnQKis/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 2 more capture groups

```
^Contact POC: ([^-]+) - (.*?) Impact:.*? (P-\d+) .*? at: (\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\D*\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})\b
```

- `^Contact POC: ([^-]+)` Start of string, match POC in **group 1**
- `-`  Match space `-` space
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 2**, matching as least possible chars for the summary
- `Impact:.*? (P-\d+)` Match Impact: and then as least as possible chars and capture `P-` and 1+ digits  in **group 3**
- `.*? at:` Match as least as possible chars to `at:`
- `(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\D*\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})` Capture the date part in **group 4** where `\D*` matches non digits in between the time and date
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3gKh2c/1)